# How an IoT sensor based device communicates with the cloud?

Tags: cloud, device, iot, communication

So, how  does an IoT sensor based device communicates with the cloud?
Does it uses Google Cloud Internet of Things or WSO2 or something similar and where is this API running from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It uses whatever it was designed to use, there are many different possibilities.  Questions on stack exchange sites must be *specifically* answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All "Internet of Things" means is that it's a device that communicates back to a central aggregation point and it doesn't use a browser.  Most IoT devices are automated and don't even have "users" in the traditional sense (temperature sensors, scanners, toasters, etc).  So they communicate back to whatever central aggregation point they've been configured to communicate back to.  Google Cloud IoT is just a framework for setting up such an aggregation point.

The device you're referring to could possibly communicate back to there, but only if its designer told it to do so and there are many other alternatives to Google's they could have used instead.  If you want to find out where the device is sending its data I'd recommend sniffing the network traffic for destinations, protocols, and payloads.  They could provide you some clues.